# Bash - SSH Multiple commands with delay between them

Tags: bash, ssh

I am trying to connect to a submodule of a router, run some commands on it and save the output to a file. The problem I have is that the submodule requires an username and password and if put all the commands in a single script the username/pass details are sent before the prompt to enter them appears. Is there a way to set a delay between the commands, or run them in batches under the same SSH session?

I used the EOF approach and also having the commands in a separate file (preferred):

```
ssh user@root > file.log << EOF
session slot 1    # command to connect to the subslot. 
                  # a delay of about 3 sec would be required before the    credentials are sent
slot_username
slot_password
command1
command2
command3
exit
exit
EOF
```

Also, the second exit should take me out of the router, but it is just ignored.

Comment: I suggest to use `expect`.

Comment: thanks. in the end I created a script using expect. I combined it with a bash script to prompt for a menu and get user input. I'm sure there is a "smarter" way to do this but I haven't found a way to get user input via expect and use the data as variables..

Answer (score 1):

I've done this before with named pipes. Create a named pipe and send its input into the ssh command.

```
mkfifo a=rw FOO
cat FOO | ssh user@root > file.log
```

You can then write commands into FOO from another script:

```
echo username >> FOO
sleep 3
echo password >> FOO
```

However... a tool exists to do exactly what you are doing. It's called `clogin`. See docs at https://linux.die.net/man/1/clogin

Comment: the O.P. can also check to see if is local system has the `expect` package/program installed (If I understand the Q correctly). Good luck to all.